How do I expand a datetime range to one row per period of time?
I have patient encounter data with an admit datetime, discharge datetime, and some metrics like DRGWeight. I need to get a census of patients in four-hour increments or periods. Is there a way to do this with datetime fields and group them? Alternatively, just getting it broken down hourly would help, then I can do grouping in another tool.
For example, say I have the following data:
create table encounters (
    id int,
    DRGWeight decimal(10,2),
    AdmitDTS datetime,
    DischargeDTS datetime,
  );

insert into encounters values (1,'1.81','2024-01-18 10:17','2024-01-19 18:15');
insert into encounters values (2,'1.78','2024-02-07 11:37','2024-02-12 13:49');
insert into encounters values (3,'0.40','2024-01-09 05:41','2024-01-10 15:10');
insert into encounters values (4, '1.95', '2024-01-21 08:10', '2024-01-25 10:00');

I've looked up how to explode a table but that just gives me new rows for each date within the range.
My ideal state would result in encounter id "1" showing up something like the following:



id
DRGWt
AdmitDTS
DischargeDTS
CensusDTS
Shift




1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-18 11:59
3


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-18 15:59
4


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-18 19:59
5


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-18 23:59
6


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-19 3:59
1


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-19 7:59
2


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-19 11:59
3


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-19 15:59
4


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17
2024-01-19 18:15
2024-01-19 19:59
5



Edit Note: Census DTS is the last minute in the period, as I just need to count patients who were present at some point in a given four-hour period.

would the first row niot habve the census of 2024-01-18 14:16:59

Since you're already familiar with t-sql and ssms I assume it wouldn't be too difficult for you to use MS Access to populate the data against your SQL Server data source.  Either that or with VBA in Excel.  I'm certain you can do what you need in t-sql using a cursor or some kind of fancy set-based query but it's not really where t-sql shines.  In fact, it's where Excel shines.  Use formulas to generate the data and then use SSMS' rich import data capabilities to connect the spreadsheet data into your table(s) in SQL Server.

try full join on table where you have 6 once, 6 - 2, etc...

@Christopher Toms you will notice I have corrected the typo in your sample data1-95 as 1.95 in my solution below. I also added a leading zero to times 5:41 and 8:10 for readability. I suggest you do the same, and possibly switch the ssms tag for t-sql, since it seems implied, by tagging that IDE, that you're expecting an answer in the T-SQL dialect.

I notice a strong similarity with this question. Although they're not the same, the approach will be similar, because the central problem (requiring iteration / cursor to get the dates in a range) follows the same pattern.

Why is the last record in the results? At 19:59 the patient had been discharged? Is it because the patient was present at the start of the 4 hour shift (i.e. @ 16:00)? This will affect the answer but I think it should be fairly simple top resolve without cursors.

I would create a dates/calendar table if you don't have one, join this to a shifts table to get a list of 4 hour slots then just join this to the encounters data where the timeslot is between admin and discharge dates. Should be simple and no cursor required.

@rory.ap, actually, I don't have MS Access, although I could use Excel. Ultimately these data are going into Power BI for visualization & analysis and I'm simultaneously looking for possible solutions within that tool. Not sure which one is better for this transformation.

@user23781552, thank you. I've made those edits as you suggested.

@AlanSchofield, yes, that is correct. Need to count the patients in a period if they were present at any point in that period.

@ChristopherThoms Power BI has date dimensions already. Are sure you need to generate the intermediate results in SQL instead of letting Power BI do this, and aggregate along the dimension's hierarchy? In any case the easy way to solve this is to use a Calendar table

@AlanSchofield I've edited my answer to reflect your input about the benefits of a calendar table. IMHO the while loop solution is the cleanest, and I guess you could describe it as a minimal calendar table of sorts. The specifics of a full-blown calendar table becomes a matter of opinion, so I've not provided a solution for that in code.

Here's a dbfiddle to show this in action.
It does not use cursors but does require a Calendar table containing at least 1 Date column named TheDate. The fiddle contains the code to generate the calendar table if you don't have one.
Then I've recreated your sample data and also a ShiftTimes table, this could be a permanent table, it just contains shift start and end times. (Technically there is a one second gap in the shifts but I only show down to seconds for clarity)
Once the sample data is ready, a CTE is defined that combines the calendar and shift times to create shift Datetimes.
Now we have a CTE with shift start and end with dates and times, we can just look for anyone who was admitted before the end of the shift and discharged after the start of the shift, in other words, they were present at some point during that shift.
-- SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @Encounters TABLE(EncID INT, DRGWeight DECIMAL(10,2), AdmitDTS DATETIME, DischargeDTS DATETIME); 
insert into @Encounters 
values  (1, '1.81', '2024-01-18 10:17:00', '2024-01-19 18:15:00'),
        (2, '1.78', '2024-02-07 11:37:00', '2024-02-12 13:49:00'),
        (3, '0.40', '2024-01-09 05:41:00', '2024-01-10 15:10:00'),
        (4, '1.95', '2024-01-21 08:10:00', '2024-01-25 10:00:00'); 

DECLARE @ShiftTimes TABLE (ShiftID INT, ShiftStartTime TIME, ShiftEndTime TIME); 
INSERT INTO @ShiftTimes VALUES 
(1, '00:00:00', '03:59:59'),
(2, '04:00:00', '07:59:59'),
(3, '08:00:00', '11:59:59'),
(4, '12:00:00', '15:59:59'),
(5, '16:00:00', '19:59:59'),
(6, '20:00:00', '23:59:59'); 
-- END OF SAMPLE DATA 

-- Combine Calendar and Shift time to create shift DATE times
WITH Shifts AS (
SELECT 
    TheDate, 
    s.*,
    ShiftStartDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME2,CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),ShiftStartTime)+CONVERT(BINARY(3),TheDate)),
    ShiftEndDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME2,CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),ShiftEndTime)+CONVERT(BINARY(3),TheDate))
    FROM dbo.CalendarTable cal 
        JOIN (SELECT enStart = MIN(AdmitDTS), enEnd = MAX(DischargeDTS) FROM @Encounters) e -- limit the calendar table to only the range in @encounters for performance.
            ON cal.TheDate between enstart and enEnd
    CROSS JOIN @ShiftTimes s 
) 
-- Final select looks for anyone admitted before the end of the shift and discharged after the start of the shift
SELECT 
        e.*,
        CensusDTS = s.ShiftEndDateTime,
        Shift = s.ShiftID
    FROM Shifts s 
    JOIN @Encounters e 
        on e.AdmitDTS <= ShiftEndDateTime and e.DischargeDTS >= ShiftStartDateTime
    ORDER BY e.EncID, TheDate, s.ShiftID


I found the while loop solution above (with the filter for id = 1 released) performs about five times faster than this one, but realise the half a second it takes to create the calendar table looks large by comparison, since the sample data is tiny. The calendar table is a one-off cost, and doesn't scale with the number of rows, which is nice, whereas the while loop does. So I think your solution will be faster on the real dataset.

Having a Calendar table is incredibly useful for so many thing when you have to work with dates. Once you have one permanently in the database, there is no cost as you say. Execution time on my test server with only a single cpu and 16gb ram only took 0.15 seconds (as I have a permanent calendar table available).

Yes, agreed. Where the calendar table would shine most is where it's being used frequently or repetitively. The efficiency savings would accumulate over time.

If this answered your question ,please mark it as Answered (check box under vote up/down buttons). This helps others find answers to similar questions.

Explanation
Expanding a datetime range to one row per time interval requires either recursion or iteration over the intervals in the range. In this case, we are looking at days.
This can be done either with:

a while loop incrementing a date variable, or
a recursive cte incrementing a date variable, or
a cursor, or
by referencing a more comprehensive calendar table

In this example, we iterate to "create" the dates that fall between the start and end of each patient encounter, and record them as rows in a table.
Sample Data
/*
    create table for sample data
*/
create table encounters (
    id int,
    DRGWeight decimal(10,2),
    AdmitDTS datetime,
    DischargeDTS datetime,
)
insert into encounters 
values 
    (1, '1.81', '2024-01-18 10:17', '2024-01-19 18:15'),
    (2, '1.78', '2024-02-07 11:37', '2024-02-12 13:49'),
    (3, '0.40', '2024-01-09 05:41', '2024-01-10 15:10'),
    (4, '1.95', '2024-01-21 08:10', '2024-01-25 10:00')

/*
    create table of shifts
*/
create table shifts (
    id int unique not null,
    StartTS time unique not null,
    EndTS as cast(dateadd(s, -1, dateadd(hh, 4, cast(StartTS as datetime2))) as time)
)
insert into shifts (id, StartTS)
values 
    (1, '00:00:00'),
    (2, '04:00:00'),
    (3, '08:00:00'),
    (4, '12:00:00'),
    (5, '16:00:00'),
    (6, '20:00:00')

While Loop Solution
/*
    iterate over each day in the range of possible dates that a patient was present, recording all days in a temp table
*/
drop table if exists #AllDays
create table #AllDays (encounterDate date)
declare 
    @FirstAdmission date = (select min(AdmitDTS) from encounters),
    @LastDischarge date = (select max(DischargeDTS) from encounters)
declare @DateCounter date = @FirstAdmission
while @DateCounter <= @LastDischarge
begin
    insert into #AllDays (encounterDate)
    select @DateCounter

    set @DateCounter = dateadd(dd, 1, @DateCounter)
end

Recursive Solution
We can generate the same #AllDays table, but recursively.
drop table if exists #AllDays
declare 
    @FirstAdmission date = (select min(cast(AdmitDTS as date)) from encounters),
    @LastDischarge date = (select max(cast(DischargeDTS as date)) from encounters)
;with AllDays as (
    select 
        @FirstAdmission as [Date]
    from encounters e

    union all

    select
        dateadd(dd, 1, ad.[Date]) as [Date]
    from AllDays ad
    where dateadd(dd, 1, ad.[Date]) <= @LastDischarge
)
select distinct [Date] as encounterDate 
into #AllDays
from AllDays
order by [Date]
option (maxrecursion 0)

Cursor Solution
/* 
    for each patient encounter, iterate over every date that falls between the day it started and day it ended;
        record resultant dates in a temp table
*/
drop table if exists #encounterDates
create table #encounterDates (encounterId int, encounterDate date)

declare encounter cursor
for 
    select id, AdmitDTS, DischargeDTS 
    from encounters;

open encounter
declare 
    @id int,
    @AdmitDTS datetime,
    @DischargeDTS datetime
fetch next from encounter into @id, @AdmitDTS, @DischargeDTS
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    declare 
        @i int = 0,
        @n int = (select datediff(dd, @AdmitDTS, @DischargeDTS))
    while @i <= @n
    begin
        insert into #encounterDates (encounterId, encounterDate)
        select @id, dateadd(dd, @i, @AdmitDTS)
        set @i += 1
    end

    fetch next from encounter into @id, @AdmitDTS, @DischargeDTS
end

close encounter;
deallocate encounter;

See this post for explanation of the performance impact cursors can have.
Calendar Table
Depending on your permissions and use cases, it may be worth investing in a permanent table representing the time points in a calendar, covering whichever range of dates and set of intervals you expect to find useful, database-wide. If you work with times and dates a lot, having one of these in your database may be worthwhile.
Some articles for more detail:
SQL shack,
MSSQL Tips
Assigning Shifts
Here we allocate shifts to each day.
This section would not be necessary if a table existed that listed all shifts against a given date. Rows could be generated as needed, as shifts are planned in the hospital.
/*
    get all possible days that at least one patients was present, and shifts that started while they were present
*/
drop table if exists #shiftDays
select 
    row_number() over(order by x.encounterDate, x.StartTS) as shiftDayId,
    x.*
into #shiftDays
from 
(
    select 
        ad.encounterDate, s.id as shiftId, s.StartTS, s.EndTS,
        cast(ad.encounterDate as datetime) + cast(s.StartTS as datetime) as ShiftStartDTS,
        cast(ad.encounterDate as datetime) + cast(s.EndTS as datetime) as ShiftEndDTS
    from encounters e
        left join #AllDays ad on ad.encounterDate between cast(e.AdmitDTS as date) and cast(e.DischargeDTS as date)
        cross join shifts s
) x
where 
    (
        /* not later than the last shift of the final encounter */
        cast(x.encounterDate as datetime) + cast(x.EndTS as datetime) <= (select max(e.DischargeDTS) from encounters e)
    )
    and
    (
        /* not earlier than the first shift of the first encounter */
        cast(x.encounterDate as datetime) + cast(x.EndTS as datetime) >= (select min(e.AdmitDTS) from encounters e)
    )

The cursor solution differs slightly here at the join, but is much the same otherwise.
from #encounterDates ed
    left join encounters e on ed.encounterId = e.id
    cross join shifts s

Final Select
/*
    get census time, as the end of the current shift, for all shifts during which a given patient was present
*/
select
    e.id,
    e.DRGWeight,
    e.AdmitDTS,
    e.DischargeDTS, 
    sd.shiftEndDTS as CensusDTS,
    sd.shiftId as Shift
from encounters e
    left join #shiftDays sd on 
    (
        e.AdmitDTS < sd.ShiftEndDTS            /* patient admitted before shift ends */
        and e.DischargeDTS > sd.ShiftStartDTS    /* patient discharged after shift begins */
    )
where e.id = 1
order by e.id, CensusDTS

Results



id
DRGWeight
AdmitDTS
DischargeDTS
CensusDTS
Shift




1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-18 11:59:59.000
3


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-18 15:59:59.000
4


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-18 19:59:59.000
5


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-18 23:59:59.000
6


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-19 03:59:59.000
1


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-19 07:59:59.000
2


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-19 11:59:59.000
3


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-19 15:59:59.000
4


1
1.81
2024-01-18 10:17:00.000
2024-01-19 18:15:00.000
2024-01-19 19:59:59.000
5



Demos
Feel free to try out each of the solutions on sqlfiddle:

while loop
recursion
cursor


Thank you. I will try that out later today. My understanding is that cursors are resource intensive. If I have multiple years of data to pull is that going to run for a long time? Would it be better to run the query year by year?

@ChristopherThoms yes, that's correct. I've amended the answer to include a more efficient solution that uses a while loop to achieve the same end. Of course, you can split it up by year if you like, but try the while loop option first :)

There is no need to use a cursor and cursors should be avoided when possible as they perform really badly on anything other than small datasets. I'll post an non-cursor answer shortly..
